# propagation of error from product of Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, error-propagation

Say I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, both of which I will be approximating with Taylor series $T_f(x)$ and $T_g(x)$ respectively. Lets say $f(x)$ is order $O(x^{n_1})$ and $T_f(x)$ has error of order $O(x^{m_1})$. Likewise $g(x)$ is order $O(x^{n_2})$ and $T_g(x)$ has error of order $O(x^{m_2})$.

Given that, what is the order of the error for $T_f(x)T_g(x)$?

What I have thought of so far is that $f(x)g(x) = (T_f(x)+E_f(x))(T_g(x)+E_g(x))= T_f(x)T_g(x) + E_f(x)T_g(x) +  E_g(x)T_f(x) + E_f(x)E_g(x)$

and if the orders multiply then $E_{total}=\max\{x^{n_2+m_1},x^{n_1+m_2},x^{m_2+m_1}\}$

But that looks like the error would go down, not up like it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply two truncated series you get an approximation of the product function which is as good as the lowest one:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {a_{\,0}  + a_{\,1} x + a_{\,2} x^{\,2}  +  \ldots  + O\left( {x^{\,m} } \right)} \right)\left( {b_{\,0}  + b_{\,1} x + b_{\,2} x^{\,2}  +  \ldots  + O\left( {x^{\,n} } \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = c_{\,0}  + c_{\,1} x + c_{\,2} x^{\,2}  +  \ldots  + b_{\,0} O\left( {x^{\,m} } \right) +  \ldots  + a_{\,0} O\left( {x^{\,n} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = c_{\,0}  + c_{\,1} x + c_{\,2} x^{\,2}  +  \ldots  + O\left( {x^{\,\min \,(m,\,n)} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Do you have a simple explanation as to why that is? I don't know why my intuition was off here.

Comment: Well, in very simple wording, if the first approximation is correct up to the $m$th term and the second up to the $n$th, then the multiplication - which is a linear combination of terms $j$*$k-j$ - will be correct till $j$ and $k-j$ are less than $min(m,n)$

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very interesting question and even better the answer.

If $m = n = 2$, then

$$f \cdot g = (a_0 + a_1 x + O(x^2)) \cdot (b_0 + b_1 x + O(x^2)) = a_0 b_0 + (a_1 b_0 + a_0 b_1) x + a_1 b_1 x^2 + [(a_0 + b_0) O(x^2) + (a_1 + b_1) x O(x^2) + O(x^2) O(x^2)]$$

The content of $[]$ reduces obviously to $O(x^2)$, so

$$f \cdot g = a_0 b_0 + (a_1 b_0 + a_0 b_1) x + a_1 b_1 x^2 + O(x^2)$$

What is curious here is that the order remains $ O(x^2)$ although an $x^2$ term is present in the expansion. Therefor the degree of the approximating polynomial is 2 but the other is still $O(x^2)$. Bilinear interpolation/approximation is another similar example: there is $xy$ term, so it is not linear, but the error is $O(x^2)$ and  $O(y^2)$ in each of the coordinates.